# How to track ADD errors in indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

I want to add multiple lines of data into an IndexedDB. The data will be parsed from CSV file, each line has an id. Only new id's should be added to the DB, so I use `add`. This works well so far.
**But how can i find out, which lines/objects where NOT added?** (because of duplicate id's) If I use `onerror` and inspect the object `e` on console of chrome, I can not find the object, which I send to the DB. So i only know, something was not added, but not what it was. So how to track this?

```
// ....

for (var key in csvObject.data ) {
   var request = store.add(csvObject.data[key]);
}

request.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log(e);   // e contains not the value of CSVobject.data[key]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this. Write the function within the loop and pass your object as an argument to it.

```
for (var key in csvObject.data) {
  (function(obj) {
    var request = store.add(obj);
    request.onerror = function(e) {
     console.log(obj, e.target.error, e.target.source); // some error messages
    };
  })(csvObject.data[key]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jakub. I still feared that it needs a solution like this. Not very handy. But if there is no other way, it looks like i have to go this way...

Comment: Unfortunately the event doesn't appear to store the data you pass. It contains only the error. If you want to persist the value within a loop, you must make a closure like I did above. If you wouldn't like to make a closure you could do `request.onerror = function() { console.log(this); }.bind(csvObject.data[key]);`, yet I would stick to closure.

Comment: I prefer .bind(). Is it only you personal choice to use a closure in such a case, or are the problems with the .bind() way?

Comment: It's more like a personal choice. Bind() isn't supported in older browsers, but so is indexeddb, so you don't have to care about it. The performance is slightly worse, yet it's not something that you should much care about. The main difference is that normally inside that function "this" is likely to be something else than the object you can access now. That's the difference, so remember you won't access the "original" `this` that would normally exist if you didn't call bind()

Comment: ok. which performance is better the on of the closure or of bind()? The csv imports can have several thousand lines. so a better performance would be a reason to change my mind. it's for an chrome app, so i don't have to care about oldtimers ;)

Comment: Actually the performance doesn't differ so much, bind() is for sure slightly slower than normal function call, but I don't think you should care about it. If bind() is more readable for you, use it! Remember -"Premature optimization is the root of all evil".